# Heads-up Notifications not being showed

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing an app where I am making use of the notifications using Firebase.

I have set up everything and it is working, however, I was expecting to get a `heads-up pop-up` notification when my app is in background and I am on another app like for example whatsapp.

Basically i was expecting to see a pop up from the top telling that a new notification has arrived, however, I just get the notification icon in the top bar as showed in the picture

[image]

I have checked other answers here and used the `Notification.PRIORITY_MAX` attribute, but still not working.

Here is my code for the notification:

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Tittle")
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

In the line `setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)` I have tried different possibilities like:

`setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)`
`setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)`

No success so far. Any help?

***NOTE: Android 7 on API 24***